# Updating selectors after delegate removal failed aws

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

i am buildingg a new iOS app using aws amplify, and I am receiving a strange error. First, here are the functions I am calling as written:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Amplify

enum AuthState {
    case signUp
    case login
    case confirmCode(username:  String)
    case session (user: AuthUser)
    case firstTime
}

final class SessionManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var authState: AuthState = .firstTime
    
    func getCurrentAuthUser() {
        if let user = Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() {
            authState = .session(user: user)
        } else {
            authState = .login
        }
    }
    
    func showSignUpView()
    {
        authState = .signUp
    }
    
    func showLoginView()
    {
        authState = .login
    }
    
    func signUp(username: String, password: String, email: String) -> AnyCancellable {
        
        let userAttributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email)]
        let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: userAttributes)
        
        let sink = Amplify.Auth.signUp(
            
            username: username,
            password: password,
            options: options)
          
            .resultPublisher
            .sink {
                if case let .failure(authError) = $0 {
                    print("An error occurred while registering a user \(authError)")
                }
            }
            receiveValue: { signUpResult in
                if case let .confirmUser(deliveryDetails, _) = signUpResult.nextStep {
                    print("Delivery details \(String(describing: deliveryDetails))")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.authState = .confirmCode(username: username)
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    print("Signup Complete")
                }

            }
        return sink
    }
    func confirmSignUp(for username: String, with confirmationCode: String) -> AnyCancellable {
        Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(for: username, confirmationCode: confirmationCode)
            .resultPublisher
            .sink {
                if case let .failure(authError) = $0 {
                    print("An error occurred while confirming sign up \(authError)")
                }
            }
            receiveValue: { _ in
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showLoginView()
                }
                print("Confirm signUp succeeded")
                
                
            }
    }
    
}
```

And they are being called by a simple createaccount view here:

```
import SwiftUI
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins
import Combine

struct CreateAccount: View {
  
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionManager: SessionManager
    
    @State var username = ""
    @State var email = "";
    @State var selection: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Username", text: $username).border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.black/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            TextField("Email", text: $email).border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.black/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            Button ( action: {
                
                sessionManager.signUp (
                    
                    username: username,
                    password: "dummy", email: email
                    
                    )
                
            })  {
                        Text("Submit")
            }
        
            }
            
        }
     
    }
    
    
    
    


struct CreateAccount_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CreateAccount(username: "Johnny")
    }
}
```

However, when attempting to sign a user up I receive this error in the console:

```
[Client] Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 86 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 86 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in uncovering where I am going wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you actually use the result of the sink? You're not storing in bag, you're not using it in UI. Since you don't use the result of the sink, it's deallocated immediately hence the error.

Comment: I have just copied the code from the AWS Amplify documentation so i'm not sure what you mean. Could you expand on this?